# Make variable treated as command and ifeq-statement syntax error with parentheses

Tags: bash, if-statement, makefile

I want to create a variable in my Makefile. It will be compared in ifeq-statement. But my variable name is treated like command:

```
make: dif: Command not found
```

I have:

```
dif := $(shell diff file1 <(./myprog < file2))
```

I've been reading some manuals and testing, but nothing worked. My non-working effects of it are as seen as above.

EDIT:

Made some progress, but the second problem is with ifeq-statement

```
$(eval dif = diff ./test0.out <(./rozwiązanie < ./test0.in)) // OK

ifeq ($(dif),null)
```

Gives error:

```
ifeq (diff ./test0.out <(./rozwiązanie < ./test0.in),null)
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'test' failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues here.  First, please specify what operating system you're using and what version of make; some of the above errors don't appear to have been generated by GNU make (which is the makefile syntax you're using) while others were.  So that's very strange.  Please run `make --version` and show the output.

Second, your syntax that you're using with the `shell` function is specific to the `bash` shell, but by default GNU make (like all versions of make) use the POSIX `sh` shell.  The output redirection syntax you're using there (`<(./myprog <file2)`) is not support in `sh`.  If you must use non-standard, `bash`-specific syntax you'll have to invoke `bash` directly; something like:

```
dif := $(shell bash -c 'diff file1 <(./myprog <file2)')
```

Third, your use of `eval` is incorrect.  `eval` is used to expand *makefile* syntax, not shell syntax.  This statement:

```
$(eval dif = diff ./test0.out <(./rozwiązanie < ./test0.in))
```

is absolutely identical in every way to this statement:

```
dif = diff ./test0.out <(./rozwiązanie < ./test0.in)
```

so you're not actually running the shell command at all, you're just setting the variable `dif` to this static string.

Finally, the output from `diff` will never be just the string `null`, so the if-statement:

```
ifeq ($(dif),null)
```

will never be true.